# Mod Rewrite code with out changing the url in address bar

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directoryindex

I When I call `http://www.mysite.in/abc/xyz` it should show up `http://www.mysite.in/abc/xyz/index.php` but the url shout not change in address bar and it should work with out "/" in the address. Please any one help me with .htaccess code for apache 2.2

Note: It should not list the directory content, instead it should show the page. SEO Friendly URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Without mod_rewrite solution:**

Just place this code on top of your `.htaccess` or in Apache config:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

**2. mod_rewrite solution:**

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(abx/xyz)/?$ $1/index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, I just only want make it function it for one my folder inside the side ex. to the folder "xyz" location is "/var/abc/xyz/"

Comment: Both of my suggested solutions should work for you. Try it out.

Comment: The Option "1" did not worked as I want "DirectorySlash off" let me try the "2".

Comment: Hi Anubhava, It is how it worked....  Placed the Method'2'  in htdocs root .htaccess file and added Directoryslash off and Directorindex index.php to the htaccess file inside the xyz folder.

Comment: Ok great to know it worked for you. Consider accepting the answer whenever you can.

Comment: Sure still I am with one reputation point.. But sure will accept when I am able to.

Comment: Yes SO makes you wait for few minutes before you can accept an answer.

Comment: May I know why you un-accepted the answer after 2+ years?

Comment: Hei Sorry,  Was by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it

Added the bellow code to root folder .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(abx/xyz.html)/?$ $1/index.php [L,NC]
```

And added the bellow code to the .htaccess file in side the xyz.html folder

```
DirectorySlash Off
Directoryindex index.php
Options -indexes
```